# How can I check for downstream components in an SSIS custom transform?

Tags: ssis

I am working on a custom SSIS component that has 4 asynchronous outputs.  It works just fine but now I have a user request for an enhancement and I am not sure how to handle it.  They want to use the component in another context where only 2 of the 4 outputs will be well defined.  I foolishly said that this would be trivial for me to support, I planned to just look to see if the two "undefined" streams were even connected, if not then I would skip over that part of the processing.

My problem is that I cannot figure out if an output is connected at run time, I had hoped that  the output pipeline or output buffer would be missing.  It doesn't look like that is the case; even when they are not hooked up the output and buffer are present.

Does anyone know where I should be looking to see if an output has a downstream consumer or not?

Thanks!

**Edit**:  I was never able to figure out how to do this reliably, so I ended up making this behaviour configurable by the user.  It is not automatic like I would have hoped but the difference I found between the BIDS environment and the DTExec environment pushed me to the conclusion that a component probably should not be making assumptions about the component graph it is embedded in.

Comment: can you be more specific on what you mean by 4 asynchronous outputs?

Comment: This component unpacks a series of records from a third party device. It then directs the records down various paths after they are unpacked while also emitting some framing records on other outputs.  I don't always have a single output for a single input so the component has to run asynchronously.